# How do I packaging up content files in a NUGET package for a UWP App?

Tags: uwp, nuget, nuspec

I'm attempting to to build up a NuGet package for UWP applications that contains font assets.  The DLL's seem to get deployed fine, but I can't get the fonts to be copied over to the deployed application.

This is how I'm atttempting to include them within my .nuspec file:

```
<file src="src\LagoVista.Core.UWP\Assets\Fonts\*.ttf"  target="runtimes\win10-x86\lib\uap10.0\Assets\Fonts"  />
<file src="src\LagoVista.Core.UWP\Assets\Fonts\*.ttf"  target="runtimes\win10-x64\lib\uap10.0\Assets\Fonts"  />
<file src="src\LagoVista.Core.UWP\Assets\Fonts\*.ttf"  target="runtimes\win10-arm\lib\uap10.0\Assets\Fonts"  />
<file src="src\LagoVista.Core.UWP\Assets\Fonts\*.ttf"  target="ref\uap10.0\Assets\Fonts"  />
```

This is the output from the NUGET package that was created:
[image]

Finally this is from APPX folder that was created after importing the NuGet package when my UWP app is deployed:

[image]

The Icons folder is from the application, I would have expected an additional folder to be included in that /AppX/Assets directory called Fonts with the fonts that were included in the nuget package. What is wrong with my Nuspec file to cause the files to not be included?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html) could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this guide - [Creating UWP controls as NuGet packages - Package content such as images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-uwp-controls#package-content-such-as-images)

You need to add a target file to your NuGet package. Note that the target file will go into the build folder and will automatically be applied when the NuGet package is installed.

In your case the target file would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetPlatformIdentifier)' == 'UAP'">
        <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\ref\uap10.0\Assets\Fonts">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Broken link. Try [Create UWP Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-uwp-packages) or [Creating UWP controls as NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-ui-controls).